# What is basic filesystem structure for macOS (Mojave) /usr/ at root?

Tags: macos, filesystems, root, macos-mojave

I am cleaning up my MacBook and would like to know the basic /usr/ filesystem structure so that I can delete components that are not essential in running my system, in order to have an idea about what not to touch. I got curious about this after cleaning out the /usr/local/ directory to reinstall Homebrew and to save storage on my laptop.

So the following is what I see at /usr/ with my Terminal:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel      8 Dec 25  2018 X11 -> /opt/X11
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel      8 Dec 25  2018 X11R6 -> /opt/X11
drwxr-xr-x  971 root  wheel  31072 May 22 05:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x  265 root  wheel   8480 Jun  5 23:39 include
drwxr-xr-x  322 root  wheel  10304 Jun  5 23:39 lib
drwxr-xr-x  250 root  wheel   8000 May 22 05:52 libexec
drwxr-xr-x   15 root  wheel    480 Jul 14 07:09 local
drwxr-xr-x  239 root  wheel   7648 May 22 05:52 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   46 root  wheel   1472 Oct 19  2018 share
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel    160 Sep 21  2018 standalone
```

Is there anything not needed that I can prune in this directory? Or should I leave things as they are?

Comment: I understand this question might seem inane to some, but it is for me to understand file systems better, as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to leave it as it is.

for example: the `bin` `include` `lib` folder contains the installed applications and compiled libraries on your Mac, so you could remove something from it and then once of the dependencies will be upset.

I believe it's better to not change any thing inside the `usr` folder

Comment: Thanks, I was guessing the same too. But just out of curiosity would like to know for sure. I think the only folder I should dare touch would be `/usr/local` if I want to start my Homebrew installation from scratch. I was using MacPorts before, but wanted to doing away with it and use Homebrew alone. Thanks for the response.

Comment: yes you are right, the `/usr/local/` directory contains what you install and regarding the Homebrew installed apps you will find them in `/usr/local/Cellar/`